# Does linux have something like supercache?

Tags: linux, io, cache

I installed http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/supercache.php for windows and the result is awesome.

Every program I run is faster.

Basically it uses the memory to cache data. Simple idea. I also use delay write.

Something like that in linux?

Comment: The linux kernel uses unused memory for disk caching by default. Delayed writing is also done by the I/O scheduler.

Comment: So is windows. But supercache goes one step further. Is there a way to make that disk caching bigger or longer? I know because hard disk utilization reach 100% for non SSD drive. Also supercache allow 5 seconds lazy writes (which will cause little problem due to journaling anyway)

Comment: A different kind of caching, but one you might also be interested in, is [preload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preload_%28software%29) and [prelink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelink).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux cache is a block cache not a file cache. In that respect Linux already has this feature as it's cache. It seems the only special thing about Supercache is it's a block cache and not a file cache.

From the Linux System Adminstrator's guide...

> The cache does not actually buffer files, but blocks, which are the smallest units of disk I/O (under Linux, they are usually 1 KB).   This way, also directories, super blocks, other filesystem bookkeeping data, and non-filesystem disks are cached.

http://linux.about.com/od/lsa_guide/a/gdelsa44.htm

Linux uses write-back buffering which writes to the disk after the cache. This is the same as delay write.

So Linux already has every feature of Supercache.

Comment: And yet my program run at 100% IO because there are too many random writes. Perhaps there is a way to make the lazy writes wait for 10 seconds before writing?

Comment: That guide is probably a bit dated. `4k` is the default block size on most modern Linux filesystems.